# Escape an xml string while creating xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xls

I need to create a xml file which is to be converted to an excel file(.xls), and this means that the xml has a lot of meta info in it. Its easy to write all the contents into the xml file as a text file.

```
var sw = new FileInfo(tempReportFilePath).CreateText();
sw.WriteLine("meta info and other tags")
```

However, this method does not escape characters, and when the data contains '<' or '>' or '&' etc. the xml is rendered invalid and the .xls file does not open. I can easily do a replace ( '<' with '<' and so on), but for performance reasons, this method is not suitable.

The other alternative is to use xml text writer, but with a ton of meta info, it will mean writing a lot of tags in code. With sw.WriteLine('stuff'), I could simply put parts of meta info in one tag (as a string) and write them to file. Using xslt, the problem I faced was that tags required spaces. For example, for tabular data, the top row fields could have spaces.
How to go about creating a well formed xml file with a lot of meta info, and where the chareacters ('<', '>' etc) are excaped?

Comment: Show us: 1. The source XML document; 2. The wanted result; 3. The requirements the transformation must implement. Without this important information the question is rather general and vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the WriteRaw method for writing the meta info tags. For the other data, which was required to be escaped, I used WriteString method.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`Uri.EscapeDataString(string stringToEscape)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx);
2. XDocument [tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/XDocument.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create xls in the first place, there is a nice library to do so :

http://npoi.codeplex.com/